# Error when trying to download wxPython on Windows

Tags: python, pip, command-line-interface

Completely new to python, running command ‘pip install -U wxPython’ in Command line and this is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\Pikachu>pip install -U wxPython
Collecting wxPython
  Using cached wxPython-4.1.1.tar.gz (66.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\pikachu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from wxPython) (9.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\pikachu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from wxPython) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\pikachu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from wxPython) (1.22.3)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for wxPython, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: wxPython
  Running setup.py install for wxPython ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for wxPython did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [51 lines of output]
      C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'license-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'license_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:294: DistDeprecationWarning: use_2to3 is ignored.
        warnings.warn(f"{attr} is ignored.", DistDeprecationWarning)
      running install
      running build
      C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2h0mnbul\wxpython_9be5f59f193e4bde8c6b8e211acc73c3\build.py:41: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
        from distutils.dep_util import newer, newer_group
      Will build using: "C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
      3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
      Python's architecture is 64bit
      cfg.VERSION: 4.1.1

      Running command: build
      Running command: build_wx
      Command '"C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, distutils.msvc9compiler as msvc; mc = msvc.MSVCCompiler(); mc.initialize(); print(mc.cc)"' failed with exit code 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):

        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

        File "C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize

          vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

        File "C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 140, in msvc9_query_vcvarsall

          return EnvironmentInfo(arch, ver).return_env()

        File "C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1740, in return_env

          [self.VCIncludes,

        File "C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1282, in VCIncludes

          return [join(self.si.VCInstallDir, 'Include'),

        File "C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 840, in VCInstallDir

          raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(msg)

      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      Finished command: build_wx (0.228s)
      Finished command: build (0.228s)
      WARNING: Building this way assumes that all generated files have been
      generated already.  If that is not the case then use build.py directly
      to generate the source and perform the build stage.  You can use
      --skip-build with the bdist_* or install commands to avoid this
      message and the wxWidgets and Phoenix build steps in the future.

      "C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" -u build.py build
      Command '"C:\Users\Pikachu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> wxPython

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My installer doesn't see the new "VisualStudio". This helped me. Maybe you too.

1. Download source:
   [wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl](https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/download/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl)
2. Install:

   ```
    pip install _your_path_to_src_\wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
   ```
3. Test:

   ```
    python -c "import wx; print(wx.version());"
   ```

Posible output if everything is correct: **4.1.2a1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5**

More details:
https://gist.github.com/oleksis/8637f096b97e18e00786e46465e97b34